# I need to merge and sort two multi-level PHP arrays

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm trying to merge two multi-level arrays into one and then sort them by time. This is because I'm making two different API calls to a PSA and then I need to present the data in order. I've formatted each array like the example below (using a foreach loop to reformat the entries returned by the API into something consistent):

```
$formattedNotes[$noteTime] = Array(
                "text" => $noteText,
                "author" => $noteAuthor,
                "staffThread" => $note_ByStaff,
                "id" => $noteId
            );
```

`$entryTime` is an epoch time associated with that record, and the array of both datasets are identical (each has text, author, staffThread, and id). My goal is to merge these two arrays, and then sort them by `$entryTime`

I've tried the following, but it still doesn't seem to come out sorted:

```
public static function MergeTimeAndNotesIntoArray($time, $notes)
{
    ksort($time);
    ksort($notes);
    $result = array_merge($time, $notes);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: CORRECTION: ``$entryTime`` is ``$noteTime``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly, something like this should do the trick:

```
public static function MergeTimeAndNotesIntoArray($time, $notes)
{
    $sorted = $time; // start with notes from $time
    foreach ($notes as $key => $value) { // add notes from $notes preserving keys
        $sorted[$key] = $value;
    }
    ksort($sorted); // sort everything by key
    return $sorted;
}
```